# Description to return just ClassName?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

The default description for a class instance returns "ClassName: 0x105120". How might I modify the method below to just return the "ClassName"?

```
// The code below just returns the address ...
- (NSString *)description {

 NSString *result;

 result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p", self];
    return result;
}
```

EDIT: in that case would this be correct? Although I do understand that if I want to actually get the className as an NSString I should use NSStringFromClass([self class])

```
- (id)init {
 NSLog(@"_init: %@", [self class]);
 [super init];
 return self;
}
```

thanks in advance -gary-

Comment: why don't you just use the correct way to get the name of the class `NSLog(@"_init: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]));`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

iPhoneOS: `NSStringFromClass([self class])`
<strike>MacOS: `[self className]`</strike>

... gives you an NSString with the class name

**Edit:**

For both iPhoneOS and MacOS the way to go is:

`NSStringFromClass([self class])`

Comment: `NSStringFromClass` is actually the proper way to do it on Mac OS X too. `-className` is part of a category on NSObject meant for scripting.

Comment: Or, in Objective-C 2.0 and higher, you can simply say: `NSStringFromClass(self.class)` using dot notation.